# Anyone can help me with this (jquery + table sorter)?

Tags: php, jquery, validation, internet-explorer-11

Can anyone check this: http://www.studiok.it/_sviluppo/sknewacc/trasparenza/ and tell me why it works with FF, Chrome and MSIE10 but *not* with MSIE11?

I noticed, if that matters, that the validator says:

```
Error Line 79, Column 11: No space between attributes.
<div id="div_main" class="" style="width:700px;margin:0 auto;">
```

Which also i do not understand..

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I've found only a `div` in the page, with no closing tag: `<div id=" div_main">`

Comment: It is now closed, but MSIE11 still shows no table content

Comment: I think the problem might be the empty class. Just remove the attribute and test again.

Comment: Nothing changed, the page is validate either ways, but it still doesn't load in msie

Comment: Found out it is the pager plugin, not compatible with MSIE11, thank you for your interest